# CustomStringConvertible Protocol variable name problem

Tags: swift

I have let in my struct name is  (I can't change because its coming from api)

```
let description: String
```

But when I wanted the use CustomStringConvertible protocol wanted to add

```
var description: String { ... }
```

2 same variable name is problem for me. How can I fix it?

```
    struct Contact: Codable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
        var description: String { "name: \(name)" }
        
        let id = UUID()
        let name: String
        let contactId: Int
        let email: String

        //let description: String?
    
    }
```

Comment: _"I can't change because its coming from api"_ so? Why couldn't you change it? If you think it's impossible because of `Codable` conformance, you can declare a `CodingKeys` compliant `enum` which defines the mapping between your property names and JSON keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `CodingKeys` `enum`:

```
struct Contact: Codable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { "name: \(name)" }
    
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let contactId: Int
    let email: String

    let ownDescription: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, contactId, email
        case ownDescription = "description"//structPropertyName = "jsonPropertyName"
    }
}
```